# Perl iso-8859-1 string comparison

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I wrote a small program to go through */usr/share/dict/words* finding palindromes

```
while(<>){
  chomp;
  print "$_\n" if $_ eq reverse;
}
```

However, this does not work for a list of Danish words encoded in Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1).
Just wondering how I'd go about making it work?

Comment: (If any SO'ers are looking for test cases, see http://www.daimi.au.dk/~chili/palindromer.html)

Comment: This raises the philosophical question of whether a palindrome IS a palindrome if there are accents involved. If there was a French word "efac" (no accent on the e) does it count as the reverse of "café" in which there is an accent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [locale](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?locale)? And maybe also turn on the Unicode flag on STDIN:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use locale;
binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    say if $_ eq reverse;
}
```

Without the `binmode` it could have been a nice one-liner:

```
perl -Mlocale -nE 'chomp; say if $_ eq reverse'
```

Comment: or perl -Mlocale -lnE 'say if $_ eq reverse'